# Exception treatment (redirection) at viewmodel constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception, lifecycle

The system is in Asp.Net MVC 4, C#.

The exception if being thrown before the controller method is executed. I don't know how to handle it - I'd like to redirect the user to an error page but I couldn't.

- I have a base ViewModel class that contains a SelectList to be used in a dropdown. In its constructor, the ViewModel gets its SelectListItems from the  database. This is the source of the exception.
- The index method takes the viewmodel as a parameter.
- Here it's a sketch of the code:

  ```
  class MyViewModel{
    public SelectList SelectListModel { get; set; }
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        List<X> xs = GetItemsFromDB(); // <= Exception thrown here
        List<SelectListItem> SelectListContent = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach(X x in xs)
        {
             SelectListContent.Add(new SelectListItem( Value = x.value,Text=x.text); 
        } 
        SelectListModel = new SelectList(SelectListContent , "Value", "Text"); 
    }  
  }
   public class MyController : Controller
  {

     public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model) //<< Exception thrown before entering method
     { 
      //do something
     }
  }
  ```

I've tried to put a try-catch inside the contructor with the following code in the catch:

```
            var context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
            var rc = new RequestContext(context, new RouteData());
            var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(rc);
            context.Response.Redirect(urlHelper.Action("Index", "Error", new { messagem = x.Message }), false);
            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

I took this from other SO answers, but its not working. When this block is executed the user is not redirected to the error page. Instead, MyControllers Index method continues its execution.

Comment: You should not have a model as a parameter in a GET method. And why in the world are you creating one `SelectList` and then creating another duplicate one from it. And a view model should never have code that accesses a database.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: to Stephen: but now that I have this problem, do you know a workaround?     to Niff: The exception is a failure in opeining the database ("Cannot open database etrc").

Comment: @galmeida, You problem is that everything your doing here is wrong. A view model is a dumb class containing properties only and should never access your data base - you can never even unit test this code. It is the responsibility of the controller to call your service and populate the view model. And a GET method should not have your model as a parameter - you initialize the model in the controller

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the comment. Would you point some guidelines for using ViewModels, please? I've put this way because many pages use the same dropdown, so this viewmodel is a base class for other viewmodels (and I've simplified the code here, it has 6 fields, including arrays and an instance of another class). Would it be bad to move the 'populate' to a method on that viewmodel or to a base controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best approach to catch this is to create an ExceptionFilter

```
public class CustomExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{    
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {

            if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
                return;    

            //Do yout logic here
        }
}
```

and register it global, in the RegisterGlobalFilters from FilterConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new CustomExceptionFilter());
}
```

Comment: This worked, just had to add filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true; at the end of OnException().

Comment: @galmeida could you please mark the answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

While you could use an `ExceptionFilter`, its is unnecessary. The real problem here is you incorrect use of a view model. A view model should contain only properties your need for display/edit in the view and should not access the database. Two reasons for this are

1. You can not unit test the model or any component of your app,
   including the controller, that uses the model. Even though its clear
   your not yet into unit testing, you should at least design for it (I
   guarantee that once you do, you it will become an integral part of
   your development).
2. Because your will be posting back your view model, it means that the
   `DefaultModelBinder` will initialize the model and call its
   constructor which in turn calls the database to populate your
   `SelectList`. The only reason you should need the `SelectList` in
   the POST method is because `ModelState` is invalid and you need to
   return the view. If client side validation is enabled, this would be
   rare, so you unnecessarily degrading performance by making database
   calls for data that wont be used.

Suggest you read the answers in [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Next, your GET method should not contain a parameter for you model. Two reasons for this are

1. The `DefaultModelBinder` is initializing your model and it
   adds the values of your model properties to `ModelState` and if your
   properties contain any validation attributes, then `ModelState` will
   be invalid. The side affect will be that any validation errors will
   be displayed in the initial view, and any attempt to set the value
   of your properties in the GET method will be ignored by `HtmlHelper`
   methods because they use the values from `ModelState` in preference
   to the model properties. To overcome this, you would need to use the
   `ModelState.Clear()` hack, effectively undoing what the
   `ModelBinder` has just done. Again its just pointless extra
   overhead.
2. Because you cannot have the same signature for the GET and POST
   method, you need to rename the POST method and use the overload of
   `BeginForm()` that specifies the action method name.

Instead, you should be initializing an instance of the view model inside the GET method.

Finally the code in your models constructor to generate the `SelectList` is generating one `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and then creating a second identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one (again its just unnecessary extra overhead).

From your comments, you have indicated that this will be a base view model, so I would suggest that you have a `BaseController` with the following method

```
protected void ConfigureBaseViewModel(BaseVM model)
{
  List<X> xs = GetItemsFromDB();
  model.SelectListModel = new SelectList(xs, "value", "text");
  // or model.SelectListModel = xs.Select(x => new SelectListItem{ Value = x.value, Text=x.text });
}
```

where `BaseVM` is

```
public abstract class BaseVM
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an item")] // add other display and validation attributes as necessary
  public int SelectedItem { get; set; } // or string?
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectListModel { get; set; }
  .... // other common properties
}
```

and then in the concrete controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var model = new yourConcreteModel();
  ConfigureBaseViewModel(model);
  return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(yourConcreteModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureBaseViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
  }
  // save and redirect
}
```

Similarly you might have a`private void ConfigureConcreteViewModel(yourConcreteModel model)` method in each concrete controller that assigns common values such as `SelectLists` that are needed in the GET method and POST method if the view needs to be returned.